# how to turn-off histogram-recording in omnetpp

Tags: omnet++

Currently, I am working with Omnet++ (Network Simulator), i know how to turn-off Scalars & Vectors recording, but how to do the same for Histogram (Turning-off Histogram recording) ?

I tried to turn-off the related scalars of the Histogram, but it was unsuccessful.

```
#### Histogram name #### 
"Delays for 1st Copy"

#### In order to turn of scalars recording we use this command ####
**.scalar-name.scalar-recording = true 

#### So i tried this but it doesnt work ####
**.Delays for 1st Copy.scalar-recording = true
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to remove the `histogram` statistic recording mode from your statistic declaration in the NED file.

```
@statistic[foo](record=count,mean,histogram); # remove histogram from here
```

Another option is to enable/disable statistic recording modes from the `omnetpp.ini`

Here are some of the basic recording modes in OMNeT++

```
**.result-recording-modes = default  # records count, mean
**.result-recording-modes = all      # records count, mean, max
**.result-recording-modes = -        # records none
**.result-recording-modes = mean     # records only mean (disables 'default')
```

You can have mode advanced combinations by adding or removing modes from the basic modes:

```
**.result-recording-modes = default,-vector,+histogram # records count,mean,histogram
**.result-recording-modes = all,-vector,+histogram  # --> count,mean,max,histogram
```

---

You probably need something like:

```
**.result-recording-modes = default,-histogram
```

---

To modify the modes of specific modules provide the full path between  `**` and `result-recording-modes`

```
**.fifo[*].queueLength.result-recording-modes = +vector  # default modes plus vector
```

Further details can be found at the OMNeT++ manual: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec405

Comment: So, without specifying the full path of the result-record it doesnt work ?

Comment: Also, if i want to turn off partially the histogram recording (i mean turning on only count and mean while diseabling all other stats), can i do it by putting -min,-max and so on ?